# Wordpress getting backend edit post content style to look at the same as front end css

Tags: wordpress

Hiall, I’d like to setup the backend of my wordpress site so that when I edit / add my content it looks exactly the same as it does on the frontend side. When I add content in the backend there is no styling applied to it when I am editing/adding content etc it (in theinput text box area etc).

I haven’t figured out how to do this, can I apply my front end css stylesheets to the content areas of the backend, or is this not possible???

I see I can add a stylesheet to the whole admin area via http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts which I don’t want to do, I only want to simply get my front end styles to be reflected in the editing/content/input area of the admin pages etc

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a new css file in your theme's folder called `editor-style.css` (usually) and enqueue it by adding this to your `functions.php`:

````
function my_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles' );```
````

In that css file you can use custom styles, setting them like this:

```
body#tinymce.wp-editor { 
    // your styles
}
body#tinymce.wp-editor a {
    // your styles
}
```

or you can also @import your main stylesheet (and add your extra rules after that if you need):

```
@import url( 'style.css' );
// extra styles here
body { 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Although adding typekit font's to display in the editing areas of the backend is proving a bit difficult. Do you know how I can do that?

On the front edit typekit loads the fonts like 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/xxxxxx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
`

How would i get those to showup in the backend?

Comment: You can enqueue xxxx.js as usual js for the admin and add this custom script part to any of your js files, loaded in admin. If you don't have any custom js yet - create one and enqueue as usual.